# Can we make the "learning" tag a more useful tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are 58 questions that are actually using [learning](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning), which puzzles me a bit.

Is the tag even useful? If it says something, it tells me users are asking a question because they are learning English, which seems obvious since the site is *English Language Learners*. Plus, I don't see any difference between a question asked by the users who are actively learning English (i.e. following an English class), and a question asked by users for which English is a second language.

Can we define the tag in a way that makes it helpful, and not a too generic tag meaning (for example) *I am asking the question because I am taking a class to learn English*? If it can be used to mean *this question is about learning technique* as [Damkerng T. suggests](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3049/is-learning-a-useful-tag?noredirect=1#comment7209_3049), what can we put in its tag wiki to make it clear in which cases the tag should be used? Should we rename it?

[As noted from J.R.](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3049/can-we-make-the-learning-tag-a-more-useful-tag?noredirect=1#comment7215_3049), we also have [mnemonic](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mnemonic). [learning](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning) should have a different purpose, or [mnemonic](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mnemonic) should be instead used.

Comment: When I see [tag:learning] on ELL, I think "this question is going to be about some learning technique". So, the tag is probably useful, but at the same time, it's unclear whether it's on or off-topic, or it's better asked at Language Learning.SE (since it's in public beta now). In any case, I think we should consider these questions on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: @DamkerngT.: I think that's still too broad to be useful as a tag; if it's about e.g. *vocabulary* learning techniques, we've already got a tag for that (which is misused enough as it is).

Comment: @Dam most of the problems lies in the fact that we think; we're not sure.

Comment: I think the tag _could_ be useful if we defined it. Maybe your question should solicit suggestions for how it could be defined, instead of just asking "Is it useful?"

Comment: @J.R. I changed the question as you suggested.

Comment: Cool. Now comes the hard part – figuring out what it should say :-) (and how it differs from the [mnemonic](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mnemonic) tag).

Comment: @J.R. If it were that easy, I would not have asked this question. `;-)`

Comment: @DamkerngT. Replied to your comment as well [in my answer](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/a/3054/289) :)

Answer (score 6):

In response to both the question and @DamkerngT.'s comment:

I was given a great reminder a few weeks ago by a mod on another SE site: just because your question is on-topic on another site, that doesn't mean it isn't on-topic on this site. We've dealt a lot with this on the ELL/ELU issue, but it's good to remember it can go both ways as well... We've accepted learning-technique questions for a long time, and there's no reason to stop accepting them solely because LL.SE may accept them as well.

This was initially going to be a comment, but in the process of writing it I think I came up with the answer to the question... [learning-techniques](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning-techniques)? Or something along those lines. Techniques, methodologies... Mnemonic devices are a type of learning devices ([learning-devices](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning-devices)?); we need a name for the broader category. What say you, ELL? :)

Comment: I like the idea of putting the meaning into the tag name. I think having very explicit tag names is important for ELL because the pop-up description might be difficult/cumbersome for a learner to parse when they're writing their question.

Comment: I'm not sure we need a name for broader categories, but with some examples of techniques that we would have very few questions to tag with, I might be convinced otherwise. And the naming scheme you suggest would do the trick if anything would.

Comment: My objection to the tag name currently is that a learner asking about practically anything might think that adding the tag is reasonable since their question *is* about learning English. I think the problem with be solved if the tag is renamed to "learning-techniques" or "learning-methods". "Learning-devices" refers to something else though I think.

Comment: I agree with @TIPS that the tag should not make the new users think they need to use it. [tag:learning-methods] is probably my preferred, even if I know there are users who will just read the _learning_ part and think _Oh yes, I am learning English; therefore, I have to put it in my question._ It happened with various tags in the site I moderate.

Answer (score 2):

I think we should revisit this suggestion after coming across the question

['As a 2nd language' .. Why English grammar is necessary to learn?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/85452/9161)

which is a close duplicate to an earlier question that was tagged with [learning](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning). I wanted to give it a more useful tag than grammar, but wasn't really satisfied with [learning](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning) after looking over the other questions that had been tagged with it.

I wonder if there should be a tag that combines [learning](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning) and [teaching](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teaching), because a question about learning techniques seems like it would be closely related to teaching methods.

Maybe what we need is [acquisition-and-learning](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/acquisition-and-learning)?

Comment: [tag:learning-methods]?

Comment: @NathanTuggy It's not really a question about a method or technique though. I'm not sure why I'm having angst over it; I just really dislike the grammar tag and I think the learning tag is a bit like it's younger sibling. I was going to make an attempt at the tag wiki, but couldn't come up with anything satisfying.